# how to use 'toIso8601String' in futureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to display the date with toIso8601String, but there is an error

> The method 'toIso8601String' isn't defined for the class 'int'. Try
>   correcting the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
>   'toIso8601String'

This code is also used exactly by my friend, but when I tried it there was an error..  and the date is TIMESTAMP type

```
_showActivities({DateTime index}) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: UserController.getActivityByDate(
      {"date": widget.index.toIso8601String(),
      "id" : _selectedUser
      }),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return snapshot.hasData
        ? new ItemDate(list: snapshot.data)
        : Center(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "No Activity",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              ),
            ),
          );
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `DateTime` object from your timestamp using `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch()` :

```dart
DateTime date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(dateInTimestamp);
date.toIso8601String(); // No typing error
```